# With Patch 2.5, how do I use Kanai's Cube since I have no direct access to crafting materials?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wanted to disenchant an item, but I cannot take any of the crafting materials out of the crafting material inventory. How do I use Kanai's Cube now?

Comment: Ran into this issue and thought others might have the same issue :P.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the item you want to disenchant into the cube as always, but press the "book icon" on the bottom right first. There is a new button called "Fill", which will automatically put the needed items into the cube:

[image: How to fill crafting material into Kanai's Cube]

Comment: Excellent. That's much more usable than before!